# NIC teaming and video streaming

Tags: windows, video, networking, video-streaming, nic

I am currently making a client PC which has Windows 10 on it and it is receiving a video stream over IP. I would like to have redundancy because of the nature of the system so I've created aggregated connection. I've done that by using Powershell cmdlet New-NetLbfoTeam with default settings (dynamic load balancing with switch independent teaming mode, tried LACP too) on two identical NICs which are onboard. After that Windows made a new connection and I can access the network without any problem.
I am using only one switch in this setup.

Now to the problem description - when I am using both NICs, there is lots of block noise in my stream. In some cases there is no video what so ever - just black screen. Tried playing the stream with several tools like VLC etc. no changes. When I disconnect a cable from one of the NICs, there are no problems what so ever. I would like to have redundancy on the network without current issues so I am looking for some tips in fine tuning the NIC teaming.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want to balance the traffic by source and destination, _not_ by round robin or per packet or frame. If you balance by frame or packet, you get a lot of out-of-order packet deliveries, and real-time traffic like voice or video can't handle that. The best thing would be to set it up as active/passive, rather than active/active.

Comment: EDIT: found it out about active/passive mode BUT powershell on Windows 10 is making my life more complicated.
have this command
New-NetLbfoTeam -Name "team" -TeamMembers "ethernet1","ethernet2"
It creates new teamed connection called "team" with 2 NICs.
Set-NetLbfoTeamMember -Name "ethernet2" -AdministrativeMode Standby
Following command SHOULD put the second NIC in failsafe mode but it doesn't. Instead it gives me the following error "Set-NetLbfoTeamMember : One or more parameter values passed to the method were invalid." Any suggestion?

Comment: I can't help you with the OS configuration. I just know about how LAG/EtherChannel works, and the problems inherent in load balancing.